# WKWebView Could not find specified service

Tags: swift, oauth, oauth-2.0, wkwebview

I'm using WKWebView to open a Safari window to load an OAuth request. The page loads fine; it shows "AppName wants to access your account" etc. However, when I press either the Authorize or Cancel button nothing happens and the user isn't returned to the app. The log in XCode shows the following error:

```
2019-10-13 17:01:40.988662-0400 TestApp[7887:2093353] [ProcessSuspension] 0x10e6e4780 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2019-10-13 17:02:10.885977-0400 TestApp[7887:2093353] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
```

Here's the relevant code (pressing the login button opens the webview):

```
// MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func pressedLoginButton(_ sender: Any) {

        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
        let urlRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: self.targetURL!)
        webView.load(urlRequest)
```

urlRequest is a URL string that contains the request `"https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost&scope=viewing_activity_read")`

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: nope, gave up on  the project altogether